# PowerShell: Can you grab parts of a upstream, piped command for output?

Tags: powershell

If I'm using PowerShell Cmdlets like:

Get-ADGroup -Server "my-dc" -Filter {name -like "*Blue*1"} | Get-ADGroupMember | Out-File $output

Is there a way that I can output the *found* group name inside of the text file as well?  Currently, this only outputs the group members into the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another variant:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like "*demo*"} | % { "GroupName: $($_.Name)"; Get-ADGroupMember $_ } | Out-File C:\Scripts\Group.txt
```

This will have something similar in the text file:

GroupName: DemoUsers

distinguishedName : CN=Ravikanth,CN=Users,DC=BarCamp,DC=in
name              : Ravikanth
objectClass       : user
objectGUID        : c4257f39-c84e-43e3-adb2-dfb6d13a8f2a
SamAccountName    : Ravikanth
SID               : S-1-5-21-4177501474-3918321425-3674396201-1000

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Get-ADGroup | %{
    # Here $_ is the group, do with it what you will :)
    $_
    $_ | get-ADGroupmember
}
```

Comment: Do you have a better example of the syntax?  I guess I'm missing what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ADGroup -Server "my-dc" -Filter {name -like "*Blue*1"} | Get-ADGroupMember | foreach { $_.name | out-file -FilePath $output -Append}
```